# How to avoid constructor call when route changes?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, next.js

I'm working on app which uses webSocket(socket.io). I have `Layout` component with webSocket connection initialization inside `constructor`:

```js
export default class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.props.initWebSocket();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={layoutStyle}>
      <Header />
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then I wrap each page by `Layout` component:

```js
export default function Games() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <p>Page with games</p>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

The problem that when page was changed `initWebSocket()` called again. I want to avoid reinitialization, establish it on first load only.

I've read section "Using Shared Components" from official documentation and thought that it will help me. Is it possible with next.js?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with custom `App` component - [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-app)

Just create '_app.js' file inside 'pages' folder and put initialization logic there.